# How to handle properly an ajax request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, autocomplete

I was curious about how to get autocomplete working in my test application I am developing with Laravel 4, just for practise. So I just googled it and found [this library](http://www.devbridge.com/sourcery/components/jquery-autocomplete/), with jQuery as its only dependency.

I am not an expert of JavaScript and jQuery and I don't know anything about AJAX, I just did what the manual said and with a bit of common sense figured how it worked overall.

Here's the JavaScript code that applies the autocomplete operation:

```
$('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
    serviceUrl: '/search',
    onSelect: function(suggestion) {
        $('#autocomplete-suggestions').html("<a href='users/" + suggestion.data + "'>" + suggestion.value + "</a>");
    }
})
```

I defined the services in the `routes.php` file, since it's very short:

```
Route::get('search', function() {
    $users = User::all();
    $response = array(
        "suggestions" => array()
    );
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        array_push($response["suggestions"], array("value" => $user->username, "data" => $user->id));
    }

    return Response::json($response);
});
```

The way this works got me wondering. I mean, every time the user types a character in the input box a request is made and the service is executed, which is in the routes method. This implies retrieving all the users from the database, storing them in an array and then copying it all again to a new array so it adjusts to the expected input. And then, on that json the actual search is made.

This seem very inefficient to me, since this operation has a cost and it is performed with great frequency. It would be way better if the search was made as a query against the database, instead of an object product to a couple of copies of (potentially) a lot of data.

Also, I seeded some new users with this piece of code:

```
for ($i = 0; $i<1000; $i++) {
    $user = new User;
    $user->username = 'username' . $i;
    // assign the rest of the attributes
    $user->save();
}
```

And it seemed like the search wasn't made properly. I guess this is a different issue, concerning the autocomplete library itself.

So, since I am not familiar with AJAX, I just want to know if this is the usual way to operate, or if this is indeed a terrible idea as I think. What would be the proper way to do it?

Comment: I think you are right. Your Search route handler should filter the users based on the suggestion and only return the suggested users. The way you built it now is inefficient, and I'd be surprised if it actually filters. It is common that for each change a new request is made

Comment: What @GolezTrol said, with the additional comment that you can (and arguably should) be caching the results. That will "lighten the load" on the server, since it can check the cache for the results of a search instead of hitting the database over and over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Should I be returning all users with each request and searching on the client side?**

Absolutely not. When the request is made to your server via AJAX, the search query is supplied as a query string parameter. From their docs:

> Web page that provides data for Ajax Autocomplete, in our case
>   autocomplete.ashx will receive GET request with querystring ?query=Li,
>   and it must return JSON data in the following format

You can get that from Laravel: `$query = \Input::get('query');`

You should be using that string to search on your `users` table using eloquent or whatever and returning only matching suggestions.

**Is it terrible to make a HTTP request with every keystroke?**

That library has an option called `deferRequestBy`. When given an integer value (milliseconds), it will wait this long until executing the request on a keyUp event. If another keyUp event comes in, it will cancel the first. This helps to reduce the number of concurrent requests you may be running.

https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete/blob/master/src/jquery.autocomplete.js#L384-L384

Directly from their [Readme on Github](https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete/blob/master/readme.md):

> `deferRequestBy`: Number of miliseconds to defer ajax request. Default: 0.

So to answer your question:

> So, since I am not familiar with AJAX, I just want to know if this is
>   the usual way to operate, or if this is indeed a terrible idea as I
>   think. What would be the proper way to do it?

Yes, if you use the default of 0, it probably is a terrible idea. But it doesn't have to be.

**Other points from your question:**

1. Do you really need to go to the DB and get *all* the users each time. How about caching?

Comment: Nice comment, but it doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: Great point about using the cache.  Simply using `$users = DB::table('users')->remember(10)->get();` together with deferRequestBy would make a good solution.  Would just need to search the collection for the correct user and return that.

Comment: @GolezTrol There are multiple points he/she raised, I've tried to answer them all.

Comment: I appreciate this answer, it really makes things more clear. On one had you are suggesting running the query used by the library on my users table, and on the other you and in the comments caching is suggested. Would merging these two together be the solution? I have never seen caching in laravel, but wouldn't calling `remember` each time in the service method result in caching again and again with each request, or the method is "smart" and manages it properly?